# Is $Y_t = f(X_t, \beta_t)$ $\rho$-mixing if $X_t$ and $\beta_t$ are independent and each of them are $\rho$-mixing?

Tags: probability-theory, mixing

There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472079/strong-mixing-of-a-function-of-strong-mixing-and-convergence-sequence) which says $Y_t = f(X_t, \beta_t)$ is strong mixing if $X_t$ and $\beta_t$ are independent and both strong mixing. Does this statement have any reference (book or paper)? In addition does the same apply to $\rho$-mixing sequences i.e., is $Y_t = f(X_t, \beta_t)$ $\rho$-mixing if $X_t$ and $\beta_t$ are independent and each of them are $\rho$-mixing?